# Proving of this trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, education

$$\frac{\cot \beta}{\csc \beta - 1} + \frac{\cot \beta}{\csc \beta + 1} = 2 \sec \beta$$

What I've done:

$$\frac{\frac{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta}} {\frac{1}{\sin \beta} +1} +
\frac{\frac{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta}} {\frac{1}{\sin \beta} -1}=\\
=\frac{\frac{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta}} {\frac{1-\sin\beta}{\sin \beta}} +
\frac{\frac{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta}} {\frac{1+\sin\beta}{\sin \beta}}=\\
=\cos \beta\frac{(1 - \sin\beta)}{\sin^2\beta} +  \cos \beta\frac{1 + \sin\beta}{\sin^2\beta}=\\
=\frac{ \cos \beta - \cos\beta \sin\beta + \cos\beta + \cos\beta \sin\beta}{\sin^2 \beta}=\\
=\frac{2\cos\beta}{\sin^2\beta}=\\
=\frac{2\cos\beta}{1-\cos^2\beta}$$

Right side:

$$2 \sec\beta=\frac{1}{2\cos\beta}$$

Could you tell me where I went wrong? I've tried using a proof program online (symbolab) though those steps are a bit hard for me to follow.

Note: I only want to use what I have on the left side to solve the left side.

Thank you very much.

(Might be some errors first time using math jax..)

Comment: The inconsistent use of parenthesis and sign "/" makes your argument rather difficult to follow.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli how's that?

Comment: Definitely better. I took the liberty to improve it. It seems you made a couple mistakes between the second and the third line. For instance, it should have been: $$\frac{\frac{\cos \beta}{\sin\beta}}{\frac{1+\sin\beta}{\sin\beta}}=\frac{\cos\beta}{\sin\beta} \cdot \frac{\sin \beta}{1+\sin \beta}=\cdots$$

Comment: You should not, because, indeed $$\frac{\cos \beta}{1-\sin \beta}+\frac{\cos \beta}{1+\sin \beta}=\frac{2}{\cos \beta}$$ which leads us to your other mistake of algebra: $$2\sec \beta=2\left(\sec \beta\right)=2\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\cos \beta}\right)=\frac{2}{\cos \beta}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I end up with the same end result as before. $\frac{2cos\beta}{1-cos^2\beta}$

Comment: How you end up with $1-\cos^2 \beta$ as a denominator instead of $1-\sin^2 \beta$ is a mistery to me.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I had that step but I simplified even further.... when you make it common denominators you get
$\frac{cos\beta(1+sin\beta) + cos\beta(1-sin\beta)}{(1-sin\beta) + (1 + sin\beta)}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32493/discussion-between-nitrate-and-g-sassatelli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first mistake was listening to your teacher. This has turned you into a $\sin$ / $\cos$ robot, causing you go against your better intuition and find a common denominator. So let's do that now
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\cot\beta}{\csc\beta-1}+\frac{\cot\beta}{\csc\beta+1}&=&\frac{\cot\beta}{\csc\beta-1}\cdot\frac{\csc\beta+1}{\csc\beta+1}+\frac{\cot\beta}{\csc\beta+1}\cdot\frac{\csc\beta-1}{\csc\beta-1}\\
&=&\cot\beta\bigg(\frac{\csc\beta+1}{\csc^2\beta-1}+\frac{\csc\beta-1}{\csc^2\beta-1}\bigg)\\
&=&\cot\beta\bigg(\frac{\csc\beta+1+\csc\beta-1}{\csc^2\beta-1}\bigg)\\
&=&\cot\beta\bigg(\frac{2\csc\beta}{\csc^2\beta-1}\bigg)\\
&=&\cot\beta\bigg(\frac{2\csc\beta}{\cot^2\beta}\bigg)\\
&=&2\frac{\csc\beta}{\cot\beta}\\
&=&2\csc\beta\tan\beta\\
\end{array}$$

At this point feel free to do the $\sin$/$\cos$ thingy, use the following identity
$$\tan\beta=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{\sin \beta \cos \beta}}{\frac{1}{\sin \beta \cos \beta}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos\beta}}{\frac{1}{\sin\beta}}=\frac{\sec\beta}{\csc\beta}$$
Continuing we have
$$2\csc\beta\tan\beta=2\csc\beta\cdot\frac{\sec\beta}{\csc\beta}=2\sec\beta$$
without the mess.

Comment: What's going on with $tan\beta$ how did $sin\beta$ become $\frac{1}{cos\beta}$ and $cos\beta$ too?

Comment: $\sin\beta$ didn't become $\frac{1}{\cos\beta}$. It became $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sin\beta}}$, and $\frac{1}{\cos\beta}$ became $\frac{\frac{1}{\cos\beta}}{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the third line of your derivation: the denominators should be $(1-\sin\beta)(1+\sin\beta)$, or $1-\sin^2\beta$, instead of $\sin^2\beta$.